# Embed identifier into executable for download

Tags: php, c, windows, assembly, reverse-engineering

Is it possible to automatically "embed" a unique identifier into a executable and read it ? And how to do it ?

For example, John log into my site, and press "Download my software", it will receive a specialized crafted executable with his info. Is it possible ? And how to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, just create a const string in your source code

```
const char* UniqueID = "HEYHEREISTHEKEY";
```

Then open up the exe as a binary file and replace the known value with the info. However, I doubt that this will help you accomplish something useful, especially if your goal is to prevent piracy. What is your scenario where you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It of course depends on how your executable is built. Let's assume a Windows PE executable. It has a resource section, which can be updated fairly easily (doesn't require reompile). One of the possible resource types is a string table. That means you can change any string fairly easily. From within the executable, you can access this table via [`LoadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice, and how could i modify this resource section ?